# How can I catch a memory error in a spawned thread?

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, python-multiprocessing

I've never used the multiprocessing library before, so all advice is welcome..

I've got a python program that uses the multiprocessing library to do some memory-intensive tasks in multiple processes, which occasionally runs out of memory (I'm working on optimizations, but that's not what this question is about). Sometimes, an out-of-memory error gets thrown in a way that I can't seem to catch (output below), and then the program hangs on `pool.join()` (I'm using `multiprocessing.Pool`. How can I make the program do something other than indefinitely wait when this problem occurs?

Ideally, The memory error is propagated back to the main process which then dies.

Here's the memory error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 811, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 764, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 325, in _handle_workers
    pool._maintain_pool()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 229, in _maintain_pool
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 222, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

And here's where i manage multiprocessing:

```
mp_pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_processes)
mp_results = list()
for datum in input_data:
    data_args = {
         'value': 0 // actually some other simple dict key/values
    }
    mp_results.append(mp_pool.apply_async(_process_data, args=(common_args, data_args)))
frame_pool.close()
frame_pool.join()  // hangs here when that thread dies..
for result_async in mp_results:
    result = result_async.get()
    // do stuff to collect results
// rest of the code
```

When I interrupt the hanging program, I get:

```
Process process_003:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 374, in get
    return recv()
    racquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: well if it cant reallocate memory what can you really do? you should use some defensive programming to avoid this error and if the error happens, catch it and then do some stuff to handle it. what that stuff is i dont know.

Comment: yes... I'm not sure how to catch it, as it seems to come from a thread managed by the python multiprocessing module.

Comment: you might have to look into the documentation then with what is getting thrown from what class. So as of now then it seems like the best approach is defensive programming to avoid the memory allocation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a [known bug in python's multiprocessing module](http://bugs.python.org/issue9205), fixed in python 3 ([here's a summarizing blog post I found](https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/multiprocessing-worker-processes-dying/)). There's a patch attached to [python issue 22393](http://bugs.python.org/issue22393), but that hasn't been officially applied.

Basically, if one of a multiprocess pool's sub-processes die unexpectedly (out of memory, killed externally, etc.), the pool will wait indefinitely.

Comment: Still not fixed in Python 3.6. I instead used `concurrent.Futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of `multiprocessing.Pool` and it will raise `BrokenProcessPool` exception.

Comment: Hi,
I run into the same issue (OOM on certain threads that run forever, Python 3.7). 
Anyone aware of any ways to overcome this using multiprocessing.Pool?